# Removing String from Powershell variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to return simply the active username to use later in a script, however I am currently hung up on having my variable populate only the username, excluding the domain.

```
Function Get-Username() {
$username = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username

return $username
}


Function Delimit-Username() {
$newUserName = $username -replace 'DOMAIN\',''

Write-Host $newUserName
}

Get-Username
Delimit-Username
```

Comment: `$Domain,$User = (Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem).UserName.Split('\')`

Answer (score 1):

The domain is delimited from the user by a `\`, hence you can use the `-split` operator and access the second element to get the username without the domain.

```
('DOMAIN\User' -split '\\')[1]
```

You can also access the environment variable username (`$env:username`)

Answer (score 0):

The USERNAME is also in the environment.

```
$Env:USERNAME
```